# Electron: how to expose console.log calls from installed packages?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron, google-chrome-devtools

still new to Electron/Node and am trying to debug an issue I'm experiencing with the msnodesqlv8 package. In the file that throws errors (`bootstrap.js`) there are several `console.log(...)` calls that do not appear in the DevTools console or in the command prompt where electron was called either, like those that are called in the renderer process. Is there anything that I can do to see where this is being logged?

This code is an out of the box installation of the [Electron React Boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) with nothing changed besides the installation of the msnodesqlv8 package and one line added to index.js to require it.

I have attempted to connect a separate DevTools instance to the main process debugger through electron's `--inspect` flag per [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process) and [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) guides, but they are incomplete/outdated and I cannot form the necessary connection -- or at least do not know where to find the complete information.
Sorry for the beginner question but I am a bit lost here.